# How does one replace the first matching item in a list in Scala?

Tags: scala, immutability

Let's say you have:

`List(('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('b', 1))`

and you want to replace the first `('b', 1)` with `('b', 2)`, and you don't want it to (a) waste time evaluating past the first match and (b) update any further matching tuples.

Is there a relatively concise way of doing this in Scala (i.e., without taking the list apart and re-concatenating it).  Something like an imaginary function `mapFirst` that returns the list with the first matching value incremented:

`testList.mapFirst { case ('b', num) => ('b', num + 1) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to take the whole List apart i guess. (Only until the element is found)

```
def replaceFirst[A](a : List[A], repl : A, replwith : A) : List[A] = a match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case head :: tail => if(head == repl) replwith :: tail else head :: replaceFirst(tail, repl, replwith) 
}
```

The call for example:

```
replaceFirst(List(('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('b', 1)), ('b', 1), ('b', 2))
```

Result:

```
List((a,1), (b,2), (c,1), (b,1))
```

A way with a partial function and implicits (which looks more like your mapFirst):

```
implicit class MyRichList[A](val list: List[A]) {
    def mapFirst(func: PartialFunction[A, A]) = {
      def mapFirst2[A](a: List[A], func: PartialFunction[A, A]): List[A] = a match {
        case Nil => Nil
        case head :: tail => if (func.isDefinedAt(head)) func.apply(head) :: tail else head :: mapFirst2(tail, func)
      }
      mapFirst2(list, func)
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
List(('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('b', 1)).mapFirst {case ('b', num) => ('b', num + 1)}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this solution wastes the stack. On big lists the solution will throw `StackOverflowException`. It's better to change the solution to be `@tailrec`. Usually this is done with `ListBuffer[T]` parameter on inside function.

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate such function relatively easily. The quickest (implementation-wise, not necessarily performance-wise) I could think of was something like this:

```
def replaceFirst[A](a:List[A], condition: (A)=>Boolean, transform:(A)=>(A)) = {
     val cutoff =a.indexWhere(condition)
     val (h,t) = a.splitAt(cutoff)
     h ++ (transform(t.head) :: t.tail)
}

scala> replaceFirst(List(1,2,3,4,5),{x:Int => x%2==0}, { x:Int=> x*2 })
res4: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 3, 4, 5)

scala> replaceFirst(List(('a',1),('b',2),('c',3),('b',4)), {m:(Char,Int) => m._1=='b'},{m:(Char,Int) => (m._1,m._2*2)})
res6: List[(Char, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,4), (c,3), (b,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `span` to find first element only. It shouldn't throw an exception even when `case` is not satified. Need less to say, you can specify as many cases as you like.

```
  implicit class MyRichieList[A](val l: List[A]) {

    def mapFirst(pf : PartialFunction[A, A]) = 
        l.span(!pf.isDefinedAt(_)) match {
           case (x, Nil) => x
           case (x, y :: ys) => (x :+ pf(y)) ++ ys
     }

  }

  val testList = List(('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('b', 1))
  testList.mapFirst { 
      case ('b', n) => ('b', n + 1) 
      case ('a', 9) => ('z', 9) 
  }
  // result --> List((a,1), (b,2), (c,1), (b,1))
```